# Timeglider does not let me destroy all variables with the given function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, destroy

I'm not that advanced with jQuery widgets and I have no idea how to **access** the **destroy function**. You can find that function from an older version here: https://code.google.com/p/codeset/source/browse/trunk/web/timegliderExample/js/timeglider/timeglider.timeline.widget.js?r=4

Usually you create timeglider with:

```
tg1 = $("#timelinearea").timeline({...
```

and so I tried to access that destoy function as well:

```
tg1 = $("#timelinearea").timeline.destroy();
tg1 = $("#timelinearea").destroy();
tg1.destroy();
```

But console always says function is not found. How can I access that function?

### Console output

```
"350px" timeline.js:44:8
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
"0px" timeline.js:44:8
"350px" timeline.js:44:8
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
"0px" timeline.js:44:8
"350px" timeline.js:44:8
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
"0px" timeline.js:44:8
"350px" timeline.js:44:8
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
Array [ "titlebar:", "hiddenBar" ] ba-debug.min.js:27:43
```

I don't think that is normal that the output is always multiplied. I use the timeslider on a div that I slide out and in. So that is what th 0px and 350px means. Doing when sliding out I delete the object. And by sliding in I read a json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the **official methods**. So first of all they did not work because timeglider still has issues with using the latest jQuery release somehow. So I'm now using the latest 1.* jQuery release and that works great with timeglider anyway.

So as I said this allows me to use the official methods now. First of all I initialized timeglider with:

```
function initializeTimeline(jsonfile) {
    tg1 = $("#timelinearea").timeline({
        "min_zoom":20,
        "max_zoom":60,
        "image_lane_height":10,
        "icon_folder":"timeglider/icons/",
        "data_source":"json/" + jsonfile,
        "constrain_to_data": true,
        "show_footer": false,
        "display_zoom_level": true
    });
    tg_instance = tg1.data("timeline");
};
```

and now I was able to use `tg_instance` and changed the file for instance with:

```
tg_instance.loadTimeline("json/someOtherData.json", function(){debug.log("cb!");}, true);
```

For sure the callback is not needed.

So just load the initialize method **one** time and never again and all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove #timelinearea from the DOM, use remove();

```
$("#timelinearea").remove();
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Well that is deleting just the ID. But I don't want to just destroy it. I want to wipe all the old data and then load a new json file without reloading the page. So I think that just wipe all variables will help me out =/

Comment: I see. Perhaps tg1 = undefined; then?

Comment: Already tested but the variables still exists. Even though I get no errors with that reset.

Comment: What you could do is declare your variable without using 'var' and then delete it using regular js; delete tg1;  This will result in an undeclared variable.

Comment: Tested and still the same.

Comment: Added console output.

Comment: I found http://www.avo.alaska.edu/includes/js/timeglider/kitchen_sink.html that says that I can easily load another json via given functions. But it always says function not found.